# scope of variable in nodejs inside a function

Tags: node.js, variables, scope

How to scope datat ?
Here datat is empty.
And i would like to put data in a var so i can use it outside the function.

```
var datat;
twit.search('#louieck', {include_entities:true,page:paget,maxid:maxidt}, function(data) {

// and output to the console:

datat =  data;

});
sys.puts(sys.inspect(datat));
```

Regards

Bussiere

Comment: At the time you call `sys.puts`, the callback function hasn't been called yet so `datat` is empty. Welcome to the world of asynchronicity :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'datat' is scoped outside your function. twit.search is async and therefore may not return 'data' before you check 'datat' with sys.inspect.

This should let you see datat:

```
var datat;
twit.search('#louieck', {include_entities:true,page:paget,maxid:maxidt}, function(data) {

    // and output to the console:
    datat =  data;
    sys.puts(sys.inspect(datat));

});
```

But ideally you'd use a callback like this...

```
var datat;
var callback = function(d){
    sys.puts(sys.inspect(d));

    datat = d;
    // do something more with datat

};

twit.search('#louieck', {include_entities:true,page:paget,maxid:maxidt}, function(data) {

    callback(data);

});
```

**EDIT** - simplified as per comment...

```
var datat;
var callback = function(d){
  sys.puts(sys.inspect(d));
  datat = d;
  // do something more with datat
};
twit.search('#louieck', {include_entities:true,page:paget,maxid:maxidt},callback(data));
```

Comment: In the second example, you don't need the anonymous function.  Just pass `callback`.